# Fake security message playing continuously on Galaxy 7

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7

My phone just started beeping by itself immediately after displaying an ad in a piece of software I've been using without problems for almost 10 years. There is a female robot voice that repeats the same message continuously:

> Important security message.
>
> Your computer has been locked up.
>
> Your IP address was used without your knowledge or consent to visit websites that contains identity theft virus. [sic]
>
> To unlock the computer please call support immediately.
>
> Please do not attempt to shutdown or restart your computer. Doing that may lead to data loss and identity theft.
>
> The computer lock is aimed to stop illegal activity.
> Please call our support immediately.

What is this, how did it get on my phone, and how do I get rid of it?

It just stopped by itself too. It was playing for about 15 minutes. The beeps became slightly irregular at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Find the app in Settings -> Applications, and force stop it. That should stop the app from doing anything. Restarting the app should hopefully allow you to continue using it without issue.

Sometimes apps will continue playing audio in the background, and unfortunately this applies to ads as well.